# Splitting timestamp column into separate date and time columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with over 2 million timestamps (below) that I would like to use to create a scatter plot of:

```
06/22/2006 09:54:11 PM
```

I'm having a hard time splitting this time stamp into 2 columns: `date` and `time`.

The following is the sample of contents of the dataframe.

```
{'STARFIRE_INCIDENT_ID': {0: 500127850130001.0, 1: 500133070120471.0, 2: 500103630140001.0, 3: 500175150150001.0, 4: 500171620150003.0}, 'INCIDENT_DATETIME': {0: '01/01/2005 12:00:01 AM', 1: '01/01/2005 12:00:03 AM', 2: '01/01/2005 12:01:02 AM', 3: '01/01/2005 12:01:42 AM', 4: '01/01/2005 12:01:45 AM'}, 'ALARM_BOX_BOROUGH': {0: 'RICHMOND / STATEN ISLAND', 1: 'BRONX', 2: 'BROOKLYN', 3: 'QUEENS', 4: 'QUEENS'}}
```

What I want to do is split `INCIDENT_DATETIME` to `INCIDENT_DATE` and `INCIDENT_TIME`.

I have tried `df['time'] = df['INCIDENT_DATETIME'].dt.time` but I get the following error.

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Comment: you need : "df['INCIDENT_DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['INCIDENT_DATETIME'])"
to convert it from str to timestamp

Comment: I think `df['INCIDENT_DATETIME'] = df['INCIDENT_DATETIME'].astype('datetime64[ns]')` might be quite a bit faster, considering a couple million time stamps.

Comment: so far both of them are taking too long. ill give it another go once I have the time

Comment: do you need to be an actual datetime dtype? you can use split(' ') and create two columns. they'll both be strings but no converting then splitting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `INCIDENT_DATETIME` column into a datetime column first, before you can access the individual datetime components:

```
df['INCIDENT_DATETIME'] = df['INCIDENT_DATETIME'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['INCIDENT_DATE'] = df['INCIDENT_DATETIME'].dt.date
df['INCIDENT_TIME'] = df['INCIDENT_DATETIME'].dt.time
```

Comment: So I implemented this and printed ```INCIDENT_TIME``` the problem is it is all in ascending order. but the dataset is not in ascending order.                                                                   
                                                                                                      ```0          00:00:01
1          00:00:03
2          00:01:02
3          00:01:42
4          00:01:45
             ...   
8538432    23:52:00
8538433    23:52:00
8538434    23:56:00
8538435    23:58:00
8538436    23:59:00
Name: INCIDENT_TIME, Length: 8538437, dtype: object```